# I am trying to implement the functionality like "Es File explorer Lan"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stream video which are in server shared folder without downloading. I am able to download the files from the particular folder using smb i need to stream the video from the server without downloading.

I am new to android please code snippet how to start will be enough.

Comment: removed thanks greenapps

Comment: Google for Samba ans smb:// protocol.

Comment: searching from more than weak can any one help me on this ?

Comment: Unbelievable. Just look under the smb tag pages of this site which have the android tag too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some web server lib. Look for the jetty server, or nanohttpd.
I use the last one and for me work great.

Comment: I am trying this in android mobile application i had server and i need get data from that server to android mobile when both are connected to same wifi

Comment: `You can try with some web server lib.`. Of course not. That has nothing to do with Windows shares.